# Does this patent cover Discord or Discord like websites

Tags: us20170291111

In reference to the patent: [US20170291111](https://www.google.com/patents/US20170291111)

I would like to make a competitor to Discord but i found this patent I want to know if it effects my ability to make a chat with party system

Comment: Please explain your idea a little better.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a patent but a published US application.  Its status is that it is currently docketed for examination.  Until it has been examined and finalized you will not know if certain claims will or will not be allowed.  As of now it offers no patent protection for any of its claims but this may change if the patent is granted.